# How do I open different files with AndroidAsync Http Server?

Tags: javascript, android, html, server

I am building a HTTP Server using AndroidAsync-https://github.com/koush/AndroidAsync. I managed to display the content of my index.html file which is stored in my projects assets-folder.

The problem is that only half of the content is being displayed because in my index.html file I am referring to .js and .css files which I also put in the assets-folder.

What am I making wrong?

Below is the code of the MainActivity.java:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.koushikdutta.async.AsyncServer;
import com.koushikdutta.async.http.server.AsyncHttpServer;
import com.koushikdutta.async.http.server.AsyncHttpServerRequest;
import com.koushikdutta.async.http.server.AsyncHttpServerResponse;
import com.koushikdutta.async.http.server.HttpServerRequestCallback;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Context mContext;

private AsyncHttpServer server = new AsyncHttpServer();
private AsyncServer myAsyncServer = new AsyncServer();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    startServer();
}

public String readFileAsString() {
    AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();

    String index = "Nothing found";
    InputStream input;
    try {
        input = assetManager.open("index.html");
        int size = input.available();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
        input.read(buffer);
        input.close();

        index = new String(buffer);
    } catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return index;
}

private void startServer() {
    server.get("/", new HttpServerRequestCallback() {


            @Override
            public void onRequest (AsyncHttpServerRequest request, AsyncHttpServerResponse
            response){
                response.send(readFileAsString());
            }
        }

        );
        server.listen(myAsyncServer, 8080);
    }
}
```

And here my index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet/v0.7.7/leaflet.css" />
    <script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet/v0.7.7/leaflet.js"></script>
    <script src="get_coordinates.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="init()">
    <div id="map"></div>    
    <button onClick="angle()">Calculate angles</button>
    <button onClick="calcDistance()">Calculate distance</button>
    <button onClick="sendData()">Send Data to phone</button>
</body>
```

Comment: Is onRequest triggered for those files? You are not using `request` parameter.

Comment: Where are you displaying index.html? Show how you load the file please.

Comment: @greenapps In the app->src->main->assets folder I have the following files: index.html; get_coordinates.js; style.css; jquery-2.1.4.min.js. When I start the app I open a browser and type in IP:8080-then I see three buttons I created in index.html but I don't see the things which I generate the init() method I defined in the get_coordinates.js file.

Comment: You didnt react on not using request parameter. Are you serious? And place all info in your post. Not in a comment. Make a decent post.

Comment: Put a picture in the assets folder and try to display it in the html page with a src tag to begin with.

Comment: And try to load different html files first. Use the request parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I have finally decided to put all the javascript code and the styling in the index.html file and everything works just fine.